# i have css menu with dropdown menu however my dropdown menu is geting block by my jquery slideshow any way to fix it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

Hi I'm helping a friend build a web site however I'm new to this as well any pointers would help thank you. The web site is in asp.net

My Sub menue is being blocked my images any way to make the sub menue display in front of the image?

using JQuery to do the slideshow

My CSS Code

```
#cssmenu ul {margin: 0; padding: 7px 6px 0; background: #7d7d7d url('../images/overlay.png') repeat-x 0 -110px; line-height: 100%; border-radius: 1em; font: normal .8em/1.5em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);}
#cssmenu li {margin: 0 5px; padding: 0 0 8px; float: left; position: relative; list-style: none; }
#cssmenu a,
#cssmenu a:link {font-weight: bold; color: #e7e5e5; text-decoration: none; display: block; padding:  8px 20px; margin: 0; border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;   text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .3); }
#cssmenu a:hover {background: #000; color: #fff;}
#cssmenu .active a, 
#cssmenu li:hover > a {background: #666 url('../images/overlay.png') repeat-x 0 -40px; color: #444; border-top: solid 1px #f8f8f8; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2); box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2); text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 1); }
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu li:hover li a {background: none; border: none; color: #666; -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none;}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {background: #8f8f8f url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -100px !important; color: #fff !important; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .1);}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {display: block;}
#cssmenu ul ul {display: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 185px; position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 0; background: #ddd url('../images/overlay.png') repeat-x 0 0; border: solid 1px #b4b4b4; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);}
#cssmenu ul ul li {float: none; margin: 0; padding: 3px; }
#cssmenu ul ul a {font-weight: normal; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; }
#cssmenu ul:after {content: '.'; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}
* html #cssmenu  ul {height: 1%;}
```

Main page code

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li class='active'><a href="Default.aspx"><span>Home</span></a></li>
       <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Wholesale</span></a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="#"><span>Phones</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><span>Sim Cards</span></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span>Dealer Login</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span>Dealer Application</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="slider">
      <!-- start slideshow -->
      <div id="slideshow">
        <div class="slider-item"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="icon" width="950" height="304" border="0" /></a></div>
        <div class="slider-item"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="icon" width="950" height="304" border="0" /></a></div>
        <div class="slider-item"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="icon" width="950" height="304" border="0" /></a></div>
        <div class="slider-item"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="icon" width="950" height="304" border="0" /></a></div>
      </div>
      <!-- end #slideshow -->
      <div class="controls-center">
        <div id="slider_controls">
          <ul id="slider_nav">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" width="205" height="70" /></a></li>
            <!-- Slide 1 -->
            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" width="205" height="70" /></a></li>
            <!-- Slide 2 -->
            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" width="205" height="70" /></a></li>
            <!-- Slide 3 -->
            <li><a href="#"><img src="#" width="205" height="70" /></a></li>
            <!-- Slide 4 -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <!--/slider -->
```

Comment: Correctly mentioned by kennypu, z-index can be set to move the object forward or backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try z-index: 999;  I believe that z-index only goes up to 999, but worth giving it a shot.

Another option would be to apply the "z-index" to one of the child classes.  If you set the z-index on your .active or whatever class contains the dropdown, it should do the trick.

Comment: i added z-index to 999 to active i fix the problem by using asp adrotator however i do believe your solutions is correct its j query function that is overriding the z-index.

Answer (score 0):

just set the z-index for the cssmenu to something larger than that of the slideshow. for example:

```
#cssmenu { z-index: 10; }
```

Comment: tried z=index: 1000; does not work something is overriding it

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle that replicates the problem?

Comment: sorry new to asp have no idea which file however i used adrotator which fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

z-index is the place you want to put it in z dimension. It is like a 3d picture. If you want to put an object above another just make one of them z-index: 10; another one z-index: 5; (Every thing has a default of z-index: 0;) So just set the z-index value greater than that of the jquery slideshow.